# How do I configure Log4J properly?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm having trouble using Log4J (version 2.13.0), with the following problems:

- I have no idea if my `log4j.properties` file is configured properly, or even recognized for that matter.
- Log4J is not using the pattern I've specified nor allowing me to log any trace/debug/info/warn messages.

This is my `log4j.properties` file:

```
status = trace
dest = out
name = PropertyConfiguration

property.filename = logs/log%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}.log
property.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | [%-5p] %c{1}:%L: %m%n

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = ${pattern}

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = logs/log-%d{MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss}.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = ${pattern}
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5

logger.rolling.name = me.tecc
logger.rolling.level = trace
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

rootLogger.level = trace
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This can help you: https://dzone.com/articles/log4j-2-configuration-using-properties-file
But again you need to change your Log4j version to minimum 2.4+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Log4J is not using the pattern I've specified nor allowing me to log any trace/debug/info/warn messages.*

> Unlike its predecessor Log4J 1.x, Log4J 2 did not support
>   configuration through the properties file when it was initially
>   released. It was from **Log4J 2.4** that support for the properties
>   file was again added, but with a completely different syntax

*I see that your Log4j version is 2.13 which falls below 2.4* , so it wont work.

**Kindly pay attention:**

The `PropertyConfigurator`(log4j.properties) does not handle the advanced configuration features supported by the `DOMConfigurator`(log4j.xml) such as support custom ErrorHandlers, nested appenders such as the AsyncAppender, etc.

Comment: I would like to point out that I am deriving my configuration from the one located at [https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties). It's nearly identical.

Comment: Check the reference 1st line that you can provided in comment, the .properties files is supported from 2.4 onwards, but you are trying it with 2.13. So it will not work.

Comment: I see. I changed the version to 2.9 (I was not aware that there were later versions (mvnrepository smh).
Thank you. It now works.

Answer (score 0):

> appender.fileName = ${filename}

you miss the "rolling" part in this config. try again after change it as follows

```
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, but the 2 other problems still remain unfixed, sadly.